# How do I get the dimensions (nestedness) of a nested vector (NOT the size)?

Tags: c++, vector

Consider the following declarations:

```
vector<vector<int> > v2d;
vector<vector<vector<string>> > v3d;
```

How can I find out the "dimensionality" of the vectors in subsequent code? For example, 2 for v2d and 3 for v3d?

Comment: C++ is strongly typed so you already know the dimension by the fact that you can use it. 2d will always be a 2 dimensional vector within the same scope.

Comment: Can you provide a context where you would not be aware of this information?

Comment: @Galik Templates.

Comment: Please note that nesting std::vectors to get multidimensional arrays is a bad practice: although a single vector is continuous in memory, the nested ones are necessarily not and require pointer chasing. This causes cache misses and could possibly be slower than it potentially could be. Also this does not guarantee that the entire multidimensional array is rectangular: any single dimension vector could accidentally be smaller causing problems.

Comment: @sim642 There is no inherent downside in the resulting array not being rectangular except for the pointer chasing. And you get that anyways here. However, slowdowns are very likely not noticeable. They might be when the structure is accessed in random order. If it is made sure that the innermost index is the one traversed the fastest (as it would be needed in a raw array as well) and unless the innermost vectors are tiny compared to a cache line, i would hesitate to apply a general label like "bad practice". It may be perfectly reasonable, depending on the situation.

Comment: I forgot: It should be noted that one major advantage of vectors is lost here or could even backfire: Their dynamic resizing. If this thing needs to resize any of its inner vectors, it might well copy the whole structure, causing massive slowdowns or hiccups in the process. It still may be perfectly reasonable if speed is no concern at all or if enough space is `reserve`d during construction. Especially as some places have a rather strict "always use STL" or "no raw pointers/arrays" policy. If you already use boost, i would still suggest `boost::multi_array` to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @DeVadder It might *move* the entire structure, you mean. Which is quite fast.

Comment: @Angew That is very much implementation dependent. Not everyone uses C++11 and before that, not even vector had a move constructor, not to speak of the arbitrary type the elements might have. And in either case, it might have to reallocate a lot of memory (note that if we speak of noticeable slowdowns as a problem, we likely talk about enormous structures with capacities likely in the thousands in any number of dimensions). And as it is not rectangular, when one column has to be resized, it is likely that the next one will have to be on the next element. Always reserve if speed is an issue.

Comment: @sim642 nested vectors destroy single buffers for growing and resizing... not exactly bad practice.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Something on these lines:

```
template<class Y> 
struct s
{
    enum {dims = 0};
};

template<class Y>
struct s<std::vector<Y>>
{
    enum {dims = s<Y>::dims + 1};
};
```

Then for example,

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > x;
int n = s<decltype(x)>::dims; /*n will be 2 in this case*/
```

Has the attractive property that all the evaluations are at *compile time*.

Comment: I prefer this solution, it's evaluated at compile time and is more similar to the "type_traits" way.

Comment: you could add support for custom allocators as well

Comment: Use the following if you want to call it like a function: `template<typename T>
constexpr size_t Rank(T const&)
{
    return s<T>::dims;
}` as `s<decltype(x)>::dims` is a bit ugly. It'll generate the same code either way (e.g. `movl    $3, %esi`)

Comment: You can us a `static constexpr size_t dims` instead of `enum`s (pre C++11).

Comment: @black or `std::integral_constant`

Comment: I wonder if this could be generalised to work for any `Container<ValueType>`, e.g. `std::list<std::list<double>>`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I'd expect not, because without concepts there's no way to test whether or not a class template is a container. You wouldn't want to write SFINAE-language for the entire container interface without that support, and even if you did you'd only be testing whether it has the right valid expressions, not whether those expressions are documented to satisfy the requirements of a container. Doing the above just for the standard containers wouldn't be a big deal, though.

Comment: Somebody posted an answer similar to this one but involving a single struct, then he(she) removed it after a few minutes.  Any how, I did had the time to implement it and it works: `template<typename T> struct rank< std::vector<T>> : publicstd::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<T>::value + 1>{};`

Answer (score 18):

You could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
int getDims(const T& vec)
{
   return 0;
}
template<typename T>
int getDims(const vector<T>& vec)
{
   return getDims(T{})+1;
}
```

Sidenote: This quantity is sometimes called "[rank](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorRank.html)".

Comment: This does construct a bunch of useless temporaries; maybe it can be improved

Comment: and makes computations at runtime

Comment: @MattMcNabb any sane compiler should be able to inline this to a constant.

Comment: @imallett `getDims` cannot be made `constexpr`: `error: temporary of non-literal type 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >' in a constant expression` . Although `v<v<v<int>>>` can be optimized , if this pattern is used for a type with a non-trivial constructor/destructor then the side-effects of `T{}` could not be optimized out. [See here](http://goo.gl/jvYhJ8) for modification that is `constexpr`

Comment: @MattMcNabb you're right; I was parsing it as something like [this](http://goo.gl/HE2YnC). My bad.

Comment: @imallett: I was thinking about that, but was afraid accessing `vec[0]` might cause a bounds check in a debug build, even if the compiler was smart enough to remove it in an optimized build.

Comment: @PiotrS. It would require some really curious algorithm to ask a matrix for its rank often enough for computation at runtime to be any issue...